# Ansible - run playbook by providing sudo hash password

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run an Ansible playbook in CLI by providing the hash of the pass.

Instead of running this command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yml  playbooks/changedefaults.yml --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=password"
```

I want to provide the hash of the string `password` like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yml  playbooks/changedefaults.yml --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=$6$rounds=656000$nv6b5eRCf0MA3Uth$YLcyFUT63rTMB8crCejv5IdyOYIpv62l5FVt.jjw4cNuqPX8HyYwmx/w48SFq/LJtYLrEV92mje7jV0Nfm/9g0"
```

How can I run this variable `ansible_sudo_pass` with the hash?

Comment: You can't: when prompting for a password, `sudo` isn't looking for the password hash. It's looking for the actual password.

Answer (score 1):

You're already in a position where you're running this command (presumably) by hand, so instead of passing the password in to the playbook in an insecure fashion, use [`ask-become-pass`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-command-line-options) instead.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yml  playbooks/changedefaults.yml --ask-become-pass
```

If you have a need to do this in autonomous fashion (e.g. you're *always* going to become some user, or root), then you should reconsider how your playbook is structured.  Using `become` is largely meant to be overseen by some responsible administrator, and isn't meant to be delegated to automation.

Comment: I run and while inserting the hash, I got this error `FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect sudo password"}`

Comment: Don't use the hash.  Use the real password when using `--ask-become-pass`.